# Помогите запустить PHP библиотеку.

Tags: php, composer

Добрый день, есть такая Composer Библиотека паука **[spatie/crawler](https://github.com/spatie/crawler)** Я ее успешно установил. Но не хватает ума правильно запустить самого паука, кто то может показать пример как просканировать например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Спасибо.

Comment: Создать класс который реализует интерфейс `\Spatie\Crawler\CrawlObserver` и запустить `Crawler::create()
    ->setCrawlObserver(/*мой скласс*/)
    ->startCrawling($url);`

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, а можно на конкретном примере, так как совершенно не понятно фраза который реализует интерфейс ООП вообще не знаю. (((

Comment: Ну тогда стоит почитать об ООП...